# Can compound assignment operators ever short circuit

Tags: c

I have some code that loops through a set a values and calls a function with each value.

like yay...

```
for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) {booleanReturn |= doFunc(i);}
```

Just curious, there isn't a compiler that will short circuit that |= right (Not execute doFunc(i) because booleanReturn is already TRUE?)

I am guessing that since this is a bitwise operator short circuit operation is not a defined behavior, but I was hoping to get some validation.

Comment: No there's no short-circuit when using the bitwise operators, not in any compiler that wants to follow the specification anyway. Short-circuit is only for the logical operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator `|=` is the compound of `operator |` not `operator ||`. The former does not short-circuit. And no operator `||=` exists. So the answer to your question is negative. `func` *must* be called if it has side effects. If it does not have side effects, then according to the *as-if rule* the implementation is free to do anything as long as you can't tell the difference.